# How to sort alphabetically a .txt file with python?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, sorting, io

I have a .txt file like with lots of ids liket this:

```
SDFSD_23423432_SDFSDF
SHTHWREWER_234324_werew
dsdfdsf_334DSFGSDF_w
....
SASFSD3452345_$534253
```

How can I create an alphabetical sorted version of this file?. This is what I tried:

```
f=open(raw_input("give me the file"))
for word in f:
    l = sorted(map(str.strip, f))
    print "\n",l
    a = open(r'path/of/the/new/sorted/file.txt', 'w')
    file.write(l)
```

But I get this exception:

```
 line 6, in <module>
    file.write(l)
TypeError: descriptor 'write' requires a 'file' object but received a 'list'
```

How can I fix this in order to create a new alphabeticaly sorted file with a new line per line, e.g. something like this:

```
id
id
id
...
id
```

Comment: The new sorted file... I got confused, I am creating new versions of this. Thanks for the feedback @thefourtheye

Comment: Where you declare `file` variable ?

Comment: Is there any other way to do this?. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, you are refering internal file object

```
>>> file
<type 'file'>
>>> file.write([])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: descriptor 'write' requires a 'file' object but received a 'list'
```

You have to write in your file object which you created in code.

```
a = open(r'path/of/the/new/sorted/file.txt', 'w')
a.write(str(l))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I got this exception: `line 8, in <module>
    a.write(l)
TypeError: expected a character buffer object` Any idea of how to fix it?

Comment: thanks for the help. I got the new file in one line... How can I give new line for each element in the list?.

Comment: If you have multiple lines then you can use [writelines](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=writeline#file.writelines). If you want to write line by line then add `\n` after each line.

Comment: I used writelines but still the same, all is in one line: `a.writelines(str(l))`. Any idea of what to do?.

Comment: use `writelines(l)` not `str(l)`